# Dependency Injection with inheritance in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have the following model:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int id {get; set;}
}
```

and two child classes:

```
public class ChildA : BaseClass {}
public class ChildB : BaseClass {}
```

I need to implement a DI like this, because of specific app logic.

```
services.AddScoped<BaseClass, ChildA>();
```

But I am getting an error:

> There is no implicit conversion from ChildA to BaseClass

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it *should* work. Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing the correct classes or namespaces?

Comment: Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/fUGpV4

Answer (score 0):

It was a namespace naming problem as @Panagiotis Kanavos suggested.

Nevertheless, I am going to create a  new question since this solve this particular simple example, but It's not working for the more complex real scenario I have.